# My UDF won't work when I try to use it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, dbo

I am still kind of a beginner here but I created this UDF:

```
USE NorthWind
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM SYSOBJECTS
                 WHERE name='SaleAfterDiscount'
                 AND type ='FN')
BEGIN 
DROP FUNCTION SaleAfterDiscount;
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION SaleAfterDiscount(@pPrice AS MONEY, @pQty AS SMALLINT, @pDiscount AS REAL)
RETURNS MONEY AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @SaleAfterDiscount MONEY;
SET @SaleAfterDiscount=(@pPrice*@pQty*(1-@pDiscount));
RETURN @SaleAfterDiscount;
END;
```

Then I go to use this UDF to get a value and I get this error that says "The Multi-Part Identifier "dbo.SaleAfterDiscount" could not be bound. I am not sure what I did wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your function is completely broken. Set with nothing....there is no return. Why send in three parameters to ignore them all?

Comment: And be careful using real here. You should use decimal instead because real is an approximate datatype.

Comment: Your `IF Exists` isn't complete. You need an ending parenthesis. Among other things as stated above.

Comment: sorry sorry I typed the code wrong I fixed it

Comment: How are you trying to call the function?

Comment: I am trying to use it to get the value of a column from another table

Comment: That's not what I asked. What SQL are you using to call the function? Can you add that to your question please?

Comment: @Zachary, I didn't get any error in this function. you can check using this statement SELECT [dbo].[SaleAfterDiscount] (100,1,25) AS MONEY.

Comment: Now that you fixed all the syntax errors your code works fine. select dbo.SaleAfterDiscount(100, 2, .10)

Comment: Oh ok I didn’t know I had to put three values in the paranthyses after the UDF. I guess that made too much sense. Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: It worked now thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Since the CREATE FUNCTION does not specify a schema, it is likely it being created in a different schema (depends on your user config).

Try changing the CREATE to look like below

CREATE FUNCTION **dbo.** SaleAfterDiscount